# a visual tool for upload status of file in BigCommerce

Tags: file-upload, bigcommerce

BigCommerce allows for product options that a user can upload a file to attach to an order (think a business card printer needs art files uploaded to the order)

Once a user selects all the options, and clicks add to cart, the page uploads the selected file along with the order details and takes you to the shopping cart. The time it takes for it to load depends on the weight of the files being uploaded.

Does anyone have a solution for having a visual tool for while a file is uploading, a percentage (either bar, or numbers) can be shown (or simply a "uploading images" overlay). People who are not familiar with the site think the page has frozen - they only realize when they let it upload - sometimes files can take up to 30 seconds to upload.

Im fairly proficient at CSS and HTML5 - if there are any solutions, please advise.

Thanks!
-Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you'd need to add HTML and CSS to create and style the loading bar. For the actual function of checking the upload status and displaying the progress, I'd suggest using jQuery with [form plugin (uploadProgress function)](https://github.com/malsup/form/#uploadprogress).

The necessary steps required to accomplish this will be a bit different in Bigcommerce than you'd see in [this blog post](http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/05/ajax-image-upload-with-progressbar-with-jquery-and-php), but it is explains it in a bit more depth with examples